# StepFunctions.getExecutionHistory Error with AWS SDK on Node Lambda, "Resource type not valid in this context: stateMachine"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

I am working with the AWS SDK in a Node env lambda; I am attempting to get the execution history to check for running state machines before invoking a start.

So I have imported the SDK and can start the state machine

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const StepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

const startParams = {
  stateMachineArn: 'STATE MACHINE ARN',
  input: JSON.stringify({}),
};

StepFunctions.startExecution(startParams, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(
      'THERE WAS AN ERROR STARTING THE STATE MACHINE. DETAILS IN THE FOLLOWING LOG'
    );
    console.log({ error });
  } else {
    console.log('Step function triggered successfully.');
    console.log({ data });
  }
});
```

console output

```
Step function triggered successfully.
```

However, the results are as follows when I try to retrieve the state machines execution history, **with the same ARN**.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const StepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

const retrieveParams = {
  executionArn: 'STATE MACHINE ARN',
  maxResults: 10,
  reverseOrder: true,
};

StepFunctions.getExecutionHistory(retrieveParams, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(
      'THERE WAS AN ERROR RETRIEVING EXECUTION HISTORY. DETAILS IN THE FOLLOWING LOG'
    );
    console.log({ error });
  } else {
    console.log('Execution history retrieved successfully.');
    console.log({ data });
  }
});
```

console output 1

```
THERE WAS AN ERROR RETRIEVING EXECUTION HISTORY. DETAILS IN THE FOLLOWING LOG
```

console output 2

```
{
  error: InvalidArn: Invalid Arn: 'Resource type not valid in this context: stateMachine'
      at Request.extractError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
      at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
      at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
      at Request.transition (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
      at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
      at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
      at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
      at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
      at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
      at Request.transition (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
      at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
      at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
      at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9) {
    code: 'InvalidArn',
    time: 2021-12-08T22:19:25.017Z,
    requestId: 'REDACTED',
    statusCode: 400,
    retryable: false,
    retryDelay: 63.25312941163477
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your executionArn? you can mask sensetive part like accountId. Also by any chance are you trying to get events for Express execution?

Comment: Sure thing! My ARN is arn:aws:states:us-east-2:----------:stateMachine:Duplicate-Notification-WorkFlow

And this is a standard workflow, not express

Comment: So it's not executionArn as I don't see `:execution:` in it, instead of paasig state machine ARN you need to get execution Arn and pass that one.

Comment: You helped me tremendously! You made me realize that I was looking for an individual execution with this syntax. Not Listing the execution status'. I was able to do

```
StepFunctions.listExecutions()
```

And just give it the ARN for the step machine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The get_execution_history function expects the executionARN of a particular instance of a workflow, not the state machine ARN.

```
executionArn='arn:aws:states:us-east-2:1133443:execution:step-func-name:workflowId'
```

The executionARN can be seen on the AWS console as well.

For more details, go through official documentation
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.get_execution_history